# Excel formula that I can use to find the top 3 phrases within a selected range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of text values where I have brain regions listed in the following cells.

[image]

Within this range of cells, I want to find the top 3 brain regions, e.g. the most frequently occurring brain region, followed by the second and third most frequent.

However, I am not sure what is the best formula that I can use to accomplish this. I have searched online and I have seen that the MODE function can be used for numeric values. I am not sure if there is a function that can be used for text values.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `=COUNTIF()` function to count how often a string occurs in a given range.

**Syntax**

```
=COUNTIF(range,"string")
    
range - Range to examine, e.g. A1:A12
string - search string in quotes, e.g "striatum"
```

**Example**

```
=COUNTIF(D20:G25,"striatum")
```

This will give you a numerical value of the occurrences of "striatum" over the range displayed on your screenshot, which you can then easily process further